# Binary to Hexadecimal

Tags: code-golf, binary, hexadecimal

Convert a binary number (of any size) into a hexadecimal number.

**Input**
A *POSITIVE* binary number with just the `0`s and `1`s. A valid input will always match the following regex: `[0-1]+`. If the input is *not* a valid binary number, that is, anything not matching this regex, the output should be `0` or the program should exit, or error. The output does not need the leading `0x` nor does it need to be capitalized.

**Output**
The binary number converted to hexadecimal.

**Winning**
Original Code-Golf Rules, Lowest amount of bytes.

**Examples**

```
IN: [101]
OUT: [0x5] OR [5]

IN: [10000000010100100000]
OUT: [0x80520] OR [80520]

IN: [1010101]
OUT: [0x55] OR [55]

IN: [1111111111111111]
OUT: [0xFFFF] OR [FFFF] OR [0xffff] OR [ffff]

IN: [1012101]
OUT: [0]

IN: [a]
OUT: [0]

IN: [-1010101]
OUT: [0]

IN: [abcdef]
OUT: [0]

IN: [2]
OUT: [0]
```

Comment: Boo-urns to input validation!

Comment: Can we exit if the input isn't valid binary?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yes

Comment: This should be popularity contest or something, not code golf.

Comment: @Titus popularity-contest would be a lot better

Comment: @DirtyDev Popularity contest would NOT better.

Comment: ...note how many answers do not conform to the input validation requirements - this is one of the reasons to just not have such restrictions in code-golf.

Comment: You could shave one byte off your regex: `[01]+`

Comment: @Titus This would be closed instantly as a pop con.

Comment: 5 hours was far too quick to an accept a solution, especially one that does not meet the specs on invalid input.

Comment: In tcl, these regexp is not enough to exclude `-1010101`, may be because the `-` is the parameter indicator, example: `regexp -expanded ...`

Comment: I wish there was a "boring" close-vote reason, the "input validation" part of this spec really ruins the challenge.

Answer (score 3):

## MY, <s>8</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
⍞PrH↵
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y638//9R77yAIo9HbVv//zc0AAA)

### How?

- `⍞` line of raw input
- `P` basify
- `r` convert from binary
- `H` convert to hex
- `↵` output

Errors if input isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <strike>126</strike> <strike>119</strike> <strike>117</strike> <strike>110</strike> 104 Bytes

#### Thanks to Jakob and Zacharý

```
class A{public static void main(String[]s){System.out.print(Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(s[0],2)));}}
```

Expanded:

```
class A
{
    public static void main(String[] s)
    {
        System.out.print(Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(s[0], 2)));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can shorten with a function like this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140570/46313

Comment: Or, if you want to stick with Java 7, you can submit a method definition, e.g. `int f(String s){ ... }`. Also, you can save bytes by using `Long.toHexString` and `Long.parseLong`.

Comment: Also, remove the space after `String[]`.

Comment: @Downvoter: Why?

Comment: As @geokavel mentioned, you can use a Java 8 lambda to shorten your code, since you didn't specify in your challenge you should have a full program, and the default here on PPCG is "program or function/lambda": `s->Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(s,2))`. But, if you want to stick with a full program, you can also shorten it with Java 8 by replacing `class A{public static void main(String[]a){` with `interface A{static void main(String[]a){`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 25+1 bytes

```php
<?=dechex(bindec($argn));
```

Run as pipe with `-F`.

or 27+1 bytes: (`-R`)

```php
printf("%x",bindec($argn));
```

or 28+1 bytes: (`-F`)

```php
<?=base_convert($argn,2,16);
```

or 30+1 bytes: (`-R`)

```php
eval("printf('%x',0b$argn);");
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>72</s> 70 bytes

```
A`[^01]
T`d`l`.(?!(....)*$)
T`d`23`b\d
T`d`4-7`b.\d
T`d`89L`b..\d
a|b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w3zEhOs7AMJYrJCElISdBT8NeUUMPCDS1VDTBYkbGCUkxKWCmia55QpIelGNh6QPkgHiJNUlc//8bGhhyGRpAAZADIkCAyxDMA0qiAZCEEUgikUsXpiYxKTklNY3LCAA) Output is blank on error. Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @PunPun1000. Explanation:

```
A`[^01]
```

Delete non-binary input.

```
T`d`l`.(?!(....)*$)
```

Convert all digits not in the correct position to `a`s and `b`s instead.

```
T`d`23`b\d
```

Add 2 to digits that follow a `b`.

```
T`d`4-7`b.\d
```

Add 4 to digits two after a `b`.

```
T`d`89L`b..\d
```

Add 8 to digits three after a `b`.

```
a|b
```

The `a`s and `b`s have done their job and can be deleted.

Comment: `89A-F` can be replaced with `89L` assuming I'm reading your explanation correctly

Comment: @PunPun1000 Thanks for reminding me; I knew there was something I'd overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 168 bytes

```c
i,l,k,n;f(char*s){char*o=malloc(l=strlen(s));for(i=n=0;i<l;n+=k<<i++)if((k=s[l-i-1]-48)&&k-1)return 0;for(i=o[--l]=0;n;n/=16)k=n%16,o[l-++i]=k>9?k+55:k+48;puts(o+l-i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzRisIwEEXf/YoirMyYhm0WFTWd3Q@RPpRgNSROlqQ@id/eTaWg7hmYYe7cO0aejBkGW/rSlaw7MOc2LhPeHjPQpfU@GPCU@uiPDAlRdyGCJaZK29prFuTq2gqBtgNwlA5eWqkaudriYuGkwnjsr5GLagqGg5S@yWnW/Elqg474Q23KkINC2Ibc9@7HifV678Rqq3@vfYIg8lPU98FyX1xay4Cz26zIdDBXlZqjfm4TWR7byNv5Ua/KP8bTi/trct@HPw)

**Unrolled:**

```c
i,l,k,n;
f(char *s)
{
    // Allocate a string for the hexadecimal digits.
    // The number of digits in the hex number is
    // sure to be less or equal to that of binary.
    char *o = malloc(l=strlen(s));

    // Convert binary to decimal.
    // The function returns zero without printing
    // anything if there are extraneous characters.
    for (i=n=0; i<l; n+=k<<i++)
        if ((k=s[l-i-1]-48) && k-1) return 0;

    // Convert decimal to hexadecimal.
    for (i=o[--l]=0; n; n/=16)
        k = n%16, o[l-++i] = k>9 ? k+55 : k+48;

    // Print the number in hexadecimal.
    puts(o+l-i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 17 bytes

```
{2bGb{_9>'70?+}%}
```

Function that takes an array of bits as input.

[Test Version](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%3As%3Ai%7B2bGb%7B_9%3E'70%3F%2B%7D%25%7D~&input=1111111111111111)

```
{
2b     e# Convert from base-2 to base-10.
Gb     e# Convert from base-10 to base-16.
{      e# For each digit in the hex version...
_      e# Duplicate it.
9>     e# Check if it's greater than 9.
'70?   e# If it is, add a '7' (char) to the stack. If not, add a 0 (int).
 +     e# Add the new item to the digit. Int + char => Increment char's ASCII value by int. (e.g '7' + 10 = 'A')
}%
}
```

If necessary, here's a version that checks for invalid input (**29 bytes**):

```
{_2,|$2,=1W?*2bGb{_9>'70?+}%}
```

[Test Version](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%3As%3Ai%7B_2%2C%7C%242%2C%3D1W%3F*2bGb%7B_9%3E'70%3F%2B%7D%25%7D~&input=1101)

It outputs 0 for an empty array and throws an exception for all other invalid input.

How validation works....

```
{
_2,|$  e# Get Logical OR of input array and [0,1], sorted.
2,=    e# Does that equal [0,1]?
1W?    e# If the arrays are equal add 1 to the stack, if not add -1.
*      e# Repeat the input as many times as the number just added to the stack. 
       e# If the number is 1, the input is unchanged.
       e# If it's -1 you get an error for an invalid number of repetitions.
...
```

Comment: Does not exit, error or yield 0 for [all invalid inputs](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q%3As%3Ai%7B2bGb%7B_9%3E'70%3F%2B%7D%25%7D~&input=20).

Comment: @Jon I did it this way because of the comments on caird's Osabie answer. I guess it's not clear what "error" as a verb means.

Comment: There would be no point in specifying that the program should "do something unexpected given invalid input" as there is no valid output for invalid input, so I think "should error" is pretty clear (although as I commented under the OP I think input validation should really be avoided).

Answer (score 1):

## [6502 machine code](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/6502_Assembly) (C64), 100 bytes

```
00 C0 20 FD AE 20 9E AD 20 A3 B6 8D 1C C0 A0 00 84 FB 84 FC 29 03 AA D0 16 A2
04 A4 FB C0 FF D0 0E A4 FC A9 00 99 62 C0 A0 C0 A9 62 4C 1E AB A9 00 85 FE CA
30 1B 06 FE A4 FB E6 FB B1 22 C9 30 F0 F1 C9 31 F0 03 4C 99 AD A5 FE 09 01 85
FE D0 E2 A9 30 05 FE C9 3A 30 02 69 06 A4 FC 99 62 C0 E6 FC D0 B5
```

#### [Online demo](https://vice.janicek.co/c64/#%7B"controlPort2":"joystick","primaryControlPort":2,"keys":%7B"SPACE":"","RETURN":"","F1":"","F3":"","F5":"","F7":""%7D,"files":%7B"binhex.prg":"data:;base64,AMAg/a4gnq0go7aNHMCgAIT7hPwpA6rQFqIEpPvA/9AOpPypAJliwKDAqWJMHqupAIX+yjAbBv6k++b7sSLJMPDxyTHwA0yZraX+CQGF/tDiqTAF/sk6MAJpBqT8mWLA5vzQtQ=="%7D,"vice":%7B"-autostart":"binhex.prg"%7D%7D)

Usage: `sys49152,"[input]"`, where `[input]` is your binary string, e.g. `sys49152,"10000000010100100000"`.

**Important:** When the program was loaded from disk (like in the online demo!), **issue a `new` command first**! This is because loading the program fiddles with some BASIC pointers and the machine thinks there's no RAM left for a string...

---

**Explanation** (commented disassembly listing):

```
00 C0       .WORD $C000         ; load address
20 FD AE    JSR $AEFD           ; check for comma
20 9E AD    JSR $AD9E           ; evaluate expression
20 A3 B6    JSR $B6A3           ; get string from expression
8D 1C C0    STA $C01C           ; store input string length for CPY instruction
A0 00       LDY #$00            ; initialize counters to 0:
84 FB       STY $FB             ;    read counter
84 FC       STY $FC             ;    write counter
29 03       AND #$03            ; number of bits in first incomplete nibble
AA          TAX                 ;  -> to X register
D0 16       BNE .nibble         ; branch to nibble decoding if not 0
 .mainloop:
A2 04       LDX #$04            ; from here on 4 bits per nibble
A4 FB       LDY $FB             ; load read counter to Y
C0 04       CPY #$FF            ; compare with input length (argument modified)
D0 0E       BNE .nibble         ; not yet done -> branch to nibble decoding
A4 FC       LDY $FC             ; load store counter
A9 00       LDA #$00            ; write NUL terminator 
99 62 C0    STA .outbuf,Y       ; to output string
A0 C0       LDY #$C0            ; load address of
A9 62       LDA #$62            ; output string
4C 1E AB    JMP $AB1E           ; and jump to string output routine
 .nibble:
A9 00       LDA #$00            ; initialize value of nibble to zero
85 FE       STA $FE             ; store to temporary variable
 .nibbleloop:
CA          DEX                 ; decrement number of bits
30 1B       BMI .nibbleout      ; no bits left -> prepare for output
06 FE       ASL $FE             ; shift temporary variable left
A4 FB       LDY $FB             ; load read counter to Y
E6 FB       INC $FB             ; increment read counter
B1 22       LDA ($22),Y         ; load next input character
C9 30       CMP #$30            ; compare with '0'
F0 F1       BEQ .nibbleloop     ; if equal, handle next bit
C9 31       CMP #$31            ; compare with '1'
F0 03       BEQ .nibbleadd      ; if equal, add that bit
4C 99 AD    JMP $AD99           ; neither '0' or '1' -> type mismatch error
 .nibbleadd:
A5 FE       LDA $FE             ; load temporary variable
09 01       ORA #$01            ; set lowest bit
85 FE       STA $FE             ; store temporary variable
D0 E2       BNE .nibbleloop     ; handle next bit
 .nibbleout:
A9 30       LDA #$30            ; load character '0'
05 FE       ORA $FE             ; combine with value from temporary variable
C9 3A       CMP #$3A            ; result smaller than 0x39 ('9') ?
30 02       BMI .nibblestore    ; then store that
69 06       ADC #$06            ; otherwise add offset to get in range 'a'-'f'
 .nibblestore:
A4 FC       LDY $FC             ; load write counter
99 62 C0    STA .outbuf,Y       ; write to output string
E6 FC       INC $FC             ; increment write counter
D0 B5       BNE .mainloop       ; back to main loop
 .outbuf:                       ; "BSS", output string is stored from here
```

**Remarks:**

- Input validation is fully implemented (and takes quite a few bytes, otherwise it would be possible to directly output each decoded nibble without temporary storage)
- I took the liberty to interpret "*any length*" as "*any length my C64 system can read from a command line as a string*", which is quite limited ... 69, or if you abbreviate `sys` with `sY` 70 "bits", because the whole command line is limited to 80 characters ...  hope this is acceptable :)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 34 bytes

```r
function(x)as.hexmode(strtoi(x,2))
```

Returns `NA` for invalid input.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/T6NCM7FYLyO1Ijc/JVWjuKSoJD9To0LHSFPzf5qGkqGBoZImF5gBBUAREAECMBkwhHLQAFyJEVxJIoTShev7DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
CbQ*Ch
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fOSlQyznj/39DAygwBEIDCA8A)
[Error case](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fOSlQyznj/39DA0MjIAYA)

It's my first try ever to a Code Golf, advices welcomed!
Handles error cases \o/

The idea is to make the conversion from base 2 to base 10, and back to base 2.
Compare the result with the initial input, if it's not the same, then the conversion have failed.

```
1012101 => 0
a => empty
-1010101 => 0
abcdef => empty
2 => 0
```

#### Explanation

```
CbQ*Ch
C  # convert input from base 2 to base 10
 b # ...and back to 2
  Q # 1 if the full conversion back and return equals the input, else 0
   * # multiply to get 0 if error case
    C # convert corrected input from base 2 to base 10
     h # convert it to base 16
```

Comment: You could use `b` instead of `2B`

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <strike>27</strike> 25 bytes

```ruby
->b{'%x'%Integer('0b'+b)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU09D4JADN35FQ2GnEYx4GgCmwOLLjoRBnoUZDkIHwkG@O14d17UGF@T19e@17Tp8bHkweKGODJnYE4kOiqoWTMP2RY38xIz3/PZDmQzkLMihddel5Y/MPbB2Kki9yufIs8oV@qgyGPJnlJ@h6yCCScLJOq@a8GOzkdYjTjbeodUlEKrT@Jyu6pIHmNiUg21vCc4DZzqrqwEBCHQ/ysyJySy91NLDssT)

-2 bytes thanks to histocrat.

Inputs and outputs strings.

[String#to_i](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-to_i) vows to never throw an exception, returning `0` for many invalid inputs. That would be fine, except for this property:

`Extraneous characters past the end of a valid number are ignored.`

Meaning that `1012101` is read up to the 2 and interpreted as `101` (or 5), which is no good. We can use the stricter `Integer()` instead, which throws an exception for any number that is not binary. It lets through negative numbers, so we need to invalidate those by prepending `0b` to the input. `0` as input returns `0`, which is within the specification.

Comment: I don't think you need the `,2` unless I'm missing some corner case, since you're already specifying base 2 with the '0b'.

Comment: @histocrat This was long enough ago that I can't really remember but I suspect you're right. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 66 bytes

```
proc H b {expr {[regexp ^\[01\]+$ $b]?[format %x [scan $b %b]]:0}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY4xCsMwDEX3nOIPyVQKdsYuXXMHxwXZdbokjXEcCBif3bVCu/QNQl9PCEU7l@LDajHAILnDByQV3Kt2eIxKyFFfWrRG39W0hoUiugNqs/SuQ3RG65vIucwLeT4ghYQUX2rgwkCeqco/WBALwvW3Q8Y@3YQ@IzV@jxvUwB80uXwA)

Comment: There was a bug in fifth test case. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, <s>52</s> <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```
print(hex(int(input(),2)))
```

Comment: It's not very *golfy*

Comment: Unfortunately, since the OP changed the rules it now only differs by being a more verbose function definition.

Comment: ...plus (like the other one) does not exit, error or yield 0 for [all invalid inputs](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSFXo0DTqii1pLQoTyEjtUIjM69Eo0DHSFPzf0ERiJ2roaRraGCoBBQAAA). (Also you have not updated the TIO link from the 52 byter)

Comment: You might be able to change it to Python2 (and remove the parens after `print`), since it would error on invalid inputs due to various different reasons.

Comment: @Zacharý Sadly Python 2 doesn't seem to have a hex() builtin

Comment: Okay then, -__-

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>58</s> 57 bytes

Saved one byte using 8 bit int

```rust
|n:&str|format!("{:x}",u8::from_str_radix(n,2).unwrap());
```

Ungolfed

```rust
fn main() {
    let bin = "101";
    println!("{:x}", u8::from_str_radix(bin, 2).unwrap()); // 5
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctNCoAgEEDhvaeYXClEfxCE0lnCqECoSUalIDy7RW/5waPoQ84bwmEsCgkPg699DTBbhBF427Rc/@jIYtixEPxRd@JlHJTa6DwmH2gis9hbfE/ZySriRcYJKTXUNfQs5fwC)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin 1.1](https://kotlinlang.org), 92 bytes

### Submission

```
fun r(i:String):String{return if(i.matches(Regex("[01]+")))i.toLong(2).toString(16)else "0"}
```

### Beautified

```
fun r(i: String): String {
    return if (i.matches(Regex("[01]+"))) {    // If it is valid
        i.toLong(2)                            // Convert to Long
         .toString(16)                         // Return as hex
    } else {                                   // Otherwise
        "0"                                    // Return 0
    }
}
```

### Explanation

- The number is checked to be valid by the regex
- Kotlin to and from string methods are used to convert the string

**Unfortunately this does not run on TryItOnline, as it uses newer Kotlin features**

Answer (score 0):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 24 bytes

```
[:\'1|0'-#'0=\unbin*hex]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XUtLCoMwEN3nFA@6mKRVUJdCofdQF9FElFqVqtCFePV0oi2FvmGG95tp1tXdGueyNKd4jSg8UXTNl75s@3NjX4W7pbUQkuIoJvD9gKU/Hru9j2d/OMLkCDVv@OvqsjK2ZpKQQiaAFDUCUeChR0hJ27ah7cdlBjOueT0s89dQCjkCNENnYNppxNN2Vk8WRLRmUhWEEPzGrQv4yb0B)

Answer (score 0):

### [Dyvil](https://github.com/Dyvil/Dyvil), 32 Bytes

```
s=>Int.parseInt(s,2).toHexString
```

Pretty much self-explanatory. Throws a `NumberFormatException` for invalid inputs. Output without `0x`.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6) <s>50</s> <s>45</s> 39 bytes

```js
h=
s=>isNaN(n=+('0b'+s))?0:n.toString(16)
```

```html
<input id="i" type="text" onchange="o.innerHTML=h(i.value)"><pre id="o"></pre">
```

with thanks to Shaggy 6 bytes less. Or for a 26 byte version that returns 'NaN' instead of '0' on error:

```
s=>+('0b'+s).toString(16)
```

`'0b'` was introduced as a binary number prefix in ES6.

Comment: You should be able to save some bytes by moving the assignment of `n` within `isNaN` and then removing the parentheses from the function parameter. Also, does the `0` need to be a string?

Comment: @Shaggy - new ways to be sneaky, thanks. And also agree that  0 converts to '0' automatically when inspecting/printing the result.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 27 bytes

```python
lambda s:hex(int('0b'+s,2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XU/BCoMwDD3brwjs0BYd1B4FL7vvC7YdWm1R2Kq0OejXd7XTMfYCLy/JCyTzisPkZLTtPT7VS/cKQjOYhY0OGRWalqGSnEc0AQO0cCMFrUVNq5x3pMZGG/ZBjo/@w2GQh0FlPv/uKN31xmYpE5PiBNfRmSbVQm@2PBKXryx39SDETh4QRgf54rSCfm1g9ukfsAw5KczSmRmPHhXAjPeT5zS@AQ)

We invalidate inputs like `0b1010` or `-1010` by prefixing `0b` ourselves — because `0b0b1010` and `0b-1010` are invalid base 2 literals in Python.

Comment: `eval('0b'+s)` for a byte

Comment: No, it’s too strong! Inputs like `"0+4*5"` will yield `20`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 19 bytes ( = 18 + 1 for "-p" )

`perl6 -pe '$_=:2($_).base: 16'`

Nothing creative. The `:2(string)` construct takes the `string` and interprets it as a number in base 2. (This works for arbitrary bases up to base 36.) The `base` method takes a number and gives a string representation in the given base.

Due to `-p`, it loads one line from stdin at a time, expecting each to contain one number. If you feed it something that's not valid binary number, you get an error and the program ends.

Answer (score 0):

## Lua, <s>43</s> 40 bytes

```
print(("").format("%x",tonumber(...,2)))
```

I think it explains itself. Parses from base 2 to decimal then formats it to hex.
If it is not binary input it will simply error (tested with Lua 5.2,5.3).

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript, 28 bytes

```
x=>eval("0b"+x).toString(16)
```

`eval`s `x` with a `0b` in front of it, turning it into a binary literal. Binary literals error out on non binary values of `x`. `.toString(16)` turns `x` into a hexdecimal.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 30 + 1 (`-n`) = 31 bytes

```perl
printf"%x",!y/01//c&&oct"0b$_"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1JtUJJR7FS38BQXz9ZTS0/uUTJIEklXun/f0Mg@JdfUJKZn1f8X9fXVM/A0OC/bh4A)

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 15 bytes

```
say b2x(arg(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, 24 bytes

```
f(x)=hex(parse(Int,x,2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f8/TaNC0zYjtUKjILGoOFXDM69Ep0LHSFPzf0FRZl5JTp5GmoaSoYGhkqYmF6qIAUT0PwA)

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp, 48 bytes

```
(format t"~X"(parse-integer(read-line):radix 2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jLb8oN7FEoUSpLkJJoyCxqDhVNzOvJDU9tUijKDUxRTcnMy9V06ooMSWzQsFIU/P/f0MDKDAEQgMIDwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 19 bytes

```bash
printf %x $((2#$1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUG1QkFFQ8NIWcVQU/P///@GBlBgCIQGEB4A)

Answer (score 0):

## ><>, <s>84</s> 82 Bytes

Improved somewhat. Probably still improvable.

```
l&1>:}*{$}2\~-?\02.
~~&\?&:-1&*/1l+<
>:f1+%:}\
\?:,+1f-/.47r~
)a:;!?ln/?
.47o+*b5/
```

Old version:

```
1l&>:}*{$}2\
~~&\?&:-1&*/l +<
>:f1+%:}-f1\1-?/
\?      :,+/r~
n/?)a:;!?l <
5/.4co+*b
```

<s>I'll work on improving it later, see if I can get rid of that big chunk of whitespace.</s>

#### How it works:

(This is for the old version, new version works the same but with loops in different positions)

Implicit input, assumed to be a series of bits such as '1,1,1,0,0', with the ones place on the right, as normal.

```
l&1
```

Store the length in the registry; push 1 to the stack. The 1 will record which place we are on in the binary number.

```
   >:}*{$}2\
   \?&:-1&*/
```

Replace each bit with the value it represents. For example, 1,1,1,0 goes to 8,4,2,0.

```
~~&
```

Delete the counter and position-measurer.

```
           /l +<
           \1-?/
```

Sum the stack. Results in the number that was represented in binary.

```
>:f1+%:}-f1\
\?      :,+/
```

Convert this to hexadecimal, which unfortunately reverses it and leaves a trailing 0. For example, 28 becomes 12, 1, 0.

```
           /r~
```

Remove the trailing zero and un-reverse it.

```
n/?)a:;!?l <
5/.4co+*b
```

This is all for printing. If the value is <10, just print it normally. Otherwise, add 55 and print the ascii character of this number.

Answer (score 0):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 50 bytes

```
{:?v~
!v0>}l4%?
 r
4<]nv?)9:+++*2}*4}*8[
+"W"<.33o
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v9rKvqyOS7HMwK42x0TVnkuhiMvEJjavzF7T0kpbW1vLqFbLpFbLIppLWylcyUbP2Dj/////umX/Df4bAjEqNISLIskBAA)

Complies with the question by erroring on invalid input, but as it always ends with an error anyway, this is a bit tongue in cheek.

#### How It Works

```
{:?v~ Pops leading 0s
...

...
!v0>}l4%? Adds leading 0s until the length of the binary is divisible by 4
 r        And reverses the input
...

...                   Repeatedly take the last 4 digits of the binary
4<]nv?)9:+++*2}*4}*8[ Calculate the value of those digits and print the hexadecimal value
+"W"<.33o             If the value is above 9, print the appropriate letter
```